# Optimizing parameters for a non-standard probability density function

Tags: distributions, loss-functions, derivative, multivariate-distribution

We have a non-standard multivariate probability density function, `P(x | q)`, where x is a vector, and q are the parameters of the density. I get events `X'` from a noisy experiment, and my goal is to find q so that `x ~ P(x|q)`. Since the experiment is noisy, this does not work well, so we have designed a machine-learning model that can add the experimental noise.

Our current strategy is the following

1. Guess an initial `q0`
2. Sample `x` from `P(x | q0)`
3. transform `x` to `x'`
4. Find the dissimilarity between `x'` and `X'`, using Wasserstein distance.
5. Use this loss in conjunction with finite differences, to optimize the parameters using numerical optimization.

The issue is that the derivatives from finite differences are very noisy, as expected, and would like a better method. We have looked for alternatives to this but cannot find a good starting point and would appreciate some pointers for what is done in the field for problems of this sort.

We understand that random samples don't have a derivative, and typically, at least in the ML community, reparameterization is used to get high-quality gradients. Unfortunately, our density is convoluted, so we cannot perform a change of variables. We have also looked into using loss functions that can be represented as functions of the expectation of the density, in which case we can find a gradient, but have found no suitable solution.

We cannot use something like MLE because the transformation of `x`->`x'` is very hard to construct at the density level. It is much simpler to do at the sample level.

Any help or pointers for this problem are welcome!

Comment: It looks as if you are attempting to do something like MLE, but through simulation rather than analysis.  If it is possible, you could try massively oversampling (step 2) and a grid search (repeating step 1).

Comment: We tried grid search of parameters in the past, but it is extremely computationally intensive. Similarly, with oversampling, it struggles to optimize, as for a large number of samples, the loss function loses sensitivity due to the large number of samples.

Comment: Also, because of the transformation function, we don't have a probability density for final events, so we can't apply MLE methods